# Compositing problem; showing in Viewer Node but not Render Results

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am trying to composite for my first time my masking video. I cannot get the render I want that shows in the *Viewer Node* view of the *Image Editor*.

The final render is just the film clip without any edits. I believe one of the editors/settings is taking priority over the compositor.

[image]

There is no output node so rendering should not work but the video still renders out (untouched of course) for me.

Comment: Did you load the film clip into VSE?  If it's there, then VSE will override and you will see the version of the clip from it, without compositing.

Comment: Marty you are so cool to take the time to help...!  I will check.  Thank you.  If I did and delete the clip will it affect my project?

Comment: deleting it from the VSE will allow a fresh render to use the compositor window again.  It won't change the existing clip at all. Since the file containing the clip still exists, you can always use the Add Clip command to restore it to the VSE.

Comment: i owe you as couple beers when your in So Cal....that was it!

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you'd like I could write this as an answer and you could accept it and/or upvote it.  Not a beer, but it's how we say thanks here.

Comment: i just wonder how he could ever composite without a composite node.... ;)

Comment: Please go ahead and ask...

Answer (score 1):

This is something people run into a lot when they use the Video Sequence Editor (VSE).  If you have a clip loaded into the VSE, then the compositor is ignored, and all a new render does is render the clip.  To solve the problem remove the clip from the VSE and render away.